# Selenium IDE to select when dropdown is in AJAX

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using selenium IDE to select the dropdown on my website. As the dropdown is in AJAX, i do not know how i can select it. Currently, i used Click at function to click the dropdown, but how do i navigate to the dropdown items? Do advise me on it and hope to hear from anyone who has experiences in this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
use waitForSelectedLabel 
target: id=selProClass2
value:  value=tom
```